# Neo4j connection for IBM Watson Analytics

Tags: neo4j, database-connection, ibm-watson

There doesn't seem to be a Neo4j connection available in Watson Analytic Account Settings Data Connections. Has anyone had any experience connecting Watson to a Neo4j database?

Comment: Not sure, exactly, what your question is, but... there are a set of language specific SDK's available for Neo4j, as well as REST-based access. As it stands, there's really no programming question to answer here.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: never used IBM Watson Analytics myself.

If it supports JDBC datasources you can probably use the Neo4j JDBC driver, https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-jdbc. Be aware that the bolt based JDBC driver is pretty new, so please do report back your experiences.

Answer (score 0):

Since Watson Analytics is a web application, you cannot add your own JDBC driver.  If you feel that Neo4j would be useful, you can request an enhancement.  Just Google "ibm request for enhancement" to get a link to the site.  Or use this link: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rfe/

Alternatively, you could write a script uses the Neo4J and Watson Analytics REST APIs to upload data from Neo4J into Watson Analytics.